# Graphical intuition behind general Taylor formula

Tags: taylor-expansion, frechet-derivative

[image]

I am trying to understand the visual intuition behind this formula, beyond its formal demonstration.
If I think for a moment that $X$ and $Y$ are both equal to $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, I visualize this formula like this:

[image]

I wonder then: why does Taylor's expansion have that expression?
If I stop at the first order, the visual idea is clear because we go back to the definition of derivative.
If I stop at the second order, I also found an intuitive explanation for me, and it is the following (using a not rigorous notation):

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\approx f'(x_0)(h)\\ 
f'(x_0+h)-f'(x_0)\approx f''(x_0)(h)
\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow 
\\
\Rightarrow f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(h)+\frac{f''(x_0)(h,h)}{2}\approx f(x_0)+\frac{f'(x_0)(h)+f'(x_0+h)(h)}{2}$$

that is, using also the second derivative it is as if we were mediating two first derivatives calculated in two different points to reduce the approximation error.
This thing makes a lot of sense, but if I go to the third order I get a less intuitive expression (and I don't know if it is correct), namely:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\approx f'(x_0)(h)\\ 
f'(x_0+h)-f'(x_0)\approx f''(x_0)(h)\\
f''(x_0+h)-f''(x_0)\approx f'''(x_0)(h)
\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow 
\\
\Rightarrow f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(h)+\frac{f''(x_0)(h,h)}{2}+\frac{f'''(x_0)(h,h,h)}{6}\approx \\ \approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(h)+\frac{f''(x_0)(h,h)}{2}+\frac{f''(x_0+h)(h,h)-f''(x_0)(h,h)}{6}\approx \\ \approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(h)+\frac{f'(x_0+h)(h)-f'(x_0)(h)}{2}+\frac{f'(x_0+2h)(h)-f'(x_0+h)(h)-(f'(x_0+h)(h)-f'(x_0)(h))}{6} = \\ = f(x_0)+\frac{2}{3}\cdot f'(x_0)(h)+\frac{1}{6}\cdot f'(x_0+h)(h)+\frac{1}{6}\cdot f'(x_0+2h)(h)$$

that I can't quite understand what it means.

Am I wrong in the reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method to rewrite the Taylor expansion points out the progressive approximations obtained by considering successive derivatives. As you correctly noted, the Taylor expansion, considered up to the second derivative, can be rewritten using your approach as $$f(x_0+h)\approx f(x_0)+\\\frac{h}{2}[f'(x_0)+ f'(x_0+h)]$$

where the last term can be interpreted as an average  of the first derivative in $x_0$ and $x_0+h$, that can reduce the approximation error.

If we consider the expansion up to the third derivative, we get a better approximation of the first derivative in $x_0+h$. In fact, your method gives

$$ f(x_0+h)  \approx f(x_0)+\frac{h}{2}f'(x_0)+\frac{h}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\left[f'(x_0) +f'(x_0+h)+ f'(x_0+2h)  \right] $$

Again, the last term can be interpreted as an average  of the first derivative, calculated among the values $x_0$, $x_0+h$ and $x_0+2h$, that can reduce the approximation error.

Comment: I have a problem if I try to write it more formally:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)(h)+\frac{f''(x)(h,h)}{2}+\frac{f^{(3)}(x)(h,h,h)}{6}+o(|h|_X^3)
\\
f''(x+h)(h,h)=f''(x)(h,h)+ f^{(3)}(x)(h,h,h)+o(|h|_X^3)
\\ 
f'(x+h)(h)=f'(x)(h)+f''(x)(h,h)+\frac{f^{(3)}(h,h,h)}{2}+o(|h|_X^3)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

From here, how do you write $f(x + h) -f (x) $ in prime derivative terms only?

Comment: You have to proceed firstly by eliminating the term $h^3f^{(3)}(x)$: set it equal to $h^2[f''(x+h)-f''(x)]$ and simplify. Then eliminate the term $h^2f^{(2)}(x)$ setting it equal to $h[f'(x+h)-f'(x)]$ and simplify again.

Comment: Your last equality is incomplete (I think) because f'(x+h) should not be written approximatively equal to $f'(x)+f^{(2)}(x)(h)$, but it should be written approx. equal to: 

$$f'(x)+f^{(2)}(x)(h)+\frac{f^{(3)}(x)(h,h)}{2}$$

If we don't write in this way, we lose the 'accuracy' $\mathcal{o}(|h|^3)$, retaining only $\mathcal{o}(|h|^2)$.

Comment: Surely all these equalities are approximations, and if you want a more precise evaluation you have to consider the $O$ terms, as you correctly noted.

Comment: But searching an $\mathcal{o}(|h|^3)$-type approximation, as in the original taylor formula, I arrive (for the third order) at the system of equations in my first comment here. In that system, I can't rearrange/substitute things in order to write f(x+h)-f(x) in terms of first derivatives only.
Is it my limit or we can't do this for the third order?

Comment: For the second order we have succeeded, we have obtained an approximation of type $\mathcal{o}(|h|^2)$ (as in the original Taylor formula) of $f (x + h) -f (x)$, in terms of prime derivatives only.

Comment: From the equation $$f(x+h)\approx f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2\frac{f''(x)}{2}+h^3\frac{f^{(3)}(x)}{6}$$ with error $O(|h|^3)$ you can make the above mentioned substitution for $f^{(3)}$ obtaining $$f(x+h)\approx f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2\frac{f''(x+h)}{6}+h^2\frac{f''(x)}{3}$$

with the same error. Making the further substitution for $f''$, you directly get 

$$f(x+h)\approx f(x)+\frac h2 f'(x)+\frac h2 \left[\frac{f'(x)+ f'(x+h)+f'(h+2h)}{3}\right]$$

again with the same error.

Comment: I can't understand your last substitution: $f^{(2)}$ depends on $f^{(3)}$, as well as on $f'$.
This fact is written in the third equation of my system.

Comment: Surely. Probably the misunderstanding is in the description of the error. When you use the formula to substitute $f''$, you clearly introduce the same error of this formula. If this error is larger than that of the formula where you are making the substitution, this becomes the actual error term. When you arrive to the formula with only the first derivative in the RHS, it is natural that you have the same error of the last formula used (i.e., a $O(|h|^2)$ error.

Comment: Ok, but this is not what I'm trying to find. I'm trying to find an *equivalent* version of taylor formula (at the third order) in terms of first derivatives only. Equivalent in the sense that the new expression must approximate with a $\mathcal{o}(|h|^3)$ error, as done by original Taylor formula.

Comment: If the formula contains $f'(x)$ as the lowest-degree term, the error is $O(|h|^2)$.